# Perfect beach in Central America / Mexico?

Tags: recommendations, beaches, mexico, central-america

I've been to Tamarindo in Costa Rica, Caye Caulker, Belize and several places in Mexico. Of all the beaches I've been to in Central America, Tulum, Mexico offers the ideal combination of pleasant beach factors:

- Expansive and clean shoreline
- powder-fine sand
- And a teeming reef a couple hundred meters off the coast.

Is there another beach in Central America that provides this perfect combination - in particular, the shallow reef swimming-distance from shore?

Comment: This really doesn't fit the [faq] guidelines where you're after a specific answer.  I suggest having a read of them again, and try to reword - asking for suggestions or recommendations really is likely to garner you downvotes or close votes.  There are honestly hundreds of beaches in this area, many, many, many of which are big, clean, soft - and I suspect many of them have reefs too.  You're basically asking for a list, in its current form, and that's specifically mentioned in the [faq] too :(

Comment: Perhaps asking about a particular country, like Belize? Or asking which countries in the region have reefs, might be less broad.

Comment: I heard tulum is very good. Tamarindo is a bit seedy, a few miles away you get much nicer crowd and ambience. Good LUCK!

Comment: Some of the beaches in/around Puerto Viejo, Costa Rica (Caribbean coast) are quite nice.

Comment: *And a teeming reef a couple hundred meters off the coast.* - Eilat or Taba anyone?

Comment: Mexico is not in Central America, it's in North America. This is why it's part of NAFTA, the North American Free Trade Association. Since it's clear Mexico is included in the scope of the question I'll edit it to broaden the scope north from just Central America.

Comment: Check out Bocas Del Toro, Panama. Amazing beach's.

Answer (score 2):

2 very good places in Nicaragua.

- Playa el Coco - Rivas, Nicaragua

Very clean and quiet beach, perfect to relax.

- Corn Island - RAAS, Nicaragua

You can get there by plane, crystal clear water. (Reefs included :P)